# Why TypeScript cannot infer callback argument type based on generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I was expecting TypeScript to infer callback argument type as number in the following example but I'm getting an error.

```
type EventWatch = {
  <K extends keyof User>(eventName: `${string & K}Changed`, callback: (e: User[K]) => void): void;
};

type User = {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  age: number;
  on: EventWatch;
}

let john: User = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe',
  age: 33,
  on(eventName, callback) {
    if (eventName == 'ageChanged') {
      callback(133) //ERROR:
      /*
    TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User[K]'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
       */
    }
  }
};
```

It correctly infers the `eventName` type and recognizes it should be one of three values: "firstnameChanged", "lastnameChanged", "ageChanged". But it cannot figure out its value.

Arguments that I pass to the function are correctly resolved and it gives an error if I send a wrong argument as it should.

```
john.on('ageChanged', e => {}); //No Error
john.on('salaryChanged', e => {}); //Error: There is no such a key named salary.
```

Why it won't infer the callback argument type?

Comment: TypeScript cannot narrow or re-constrain generic type parameters based on control flow; so no amount of checking of `eventName` will narrow the type parameter `K` itself. See [ms/TS#24085](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) or [ms/TS#27808](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) for suggestions to maybe do so. But you don't need generics here, since you have a finite list of acceptable params; you should be able to use discriminated unions like [this](//tsplay.dev/NDPLxN) although depending on the version of TS you use you'll need some impl refactoring.

Comment: Would you like me to write this up into an answer or am I missing something about your question?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you! I think this is a good answer to the question. So, I can accept it if you write it up into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript does not use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow or constrain [generic type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  So when you check `eventName == 'ageChanged'`, while the type of the `eventName` variable might be narrowed, nothing will happen to `K`.  Before the check, the compiler knows that `K extends keyof User`, and the check does nothing to change this.  In particular, `K` is not re-constrained to `K extends "age"` (and in fact such a narrowing would not be safe, since maybe `K` is the full `keyof User` union type).  And therefore `callback` of type `(e: User[K]) => void` is not known to be of type `(e: number) => void`, and you get an error:

```
on(eventName, callback) {
  // (parameter) eventName: `${K}Changed`
  // (parameter) callback: (e: User[K]) => void
  if (eventName == 'ageChanged') {
    // (parameter) eventName: `${K}Changed` still
    // (parameter) callback: (e: User[K]) => void still
    callback(133) // error
  }
}
```

There are several feature requests in GitHub to allow some way to narrow generic type parameters based on control flow.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) and [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) for some of them (and they link to others).  Who knows when or even if this will be implemented.  For now, the easiest change is to suppress the error with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler what it doesn't know:

```
on(eventName, callback) {
  if (eventName == 'ageChanged') {
    (callback as (e: number)=>void)(133) // okay
  }
}
```

But this isn't type safe any longer.

---

Instead of using generics here, you might consider giving `on()` a rest parameter of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types), because there are only a finite list of possible allowable `eventName`/`callback` pair types.  And because the `eventName` parameter is a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), that means your union will be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where checking `eventName` will automatically narrow `callback` as well.

The idea is something like this:

```
type EventWatchParams = 
  [eventName: "firstnameChanged", callback: (e: string) => void] | 
  [eventName: "lastnameChanged", callback: (e: string) => void] | 
  [eventName: "ageChanged", callback: (e: number) => void] | 
  [eventName: "onChanged", callback: (e: EventWatch) => void];

type EventWatch = {
  (...args: EventWatchParams): void;
};
```

Note how this means you can only call an `EventWatch` with two parameters where the first and second parameter types depend on each other.  Of course you don't want to write out `EventWatchParams` manually; you'd like the compiler to compute it in terms of `User` automatically. Well, you can do so via a *distributive object type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where you immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), like this:

```
type EventWatchParams = {
  [K in keyof User]: [eventName: `${K}Changed`, callback: (e: User[K]) => void]
}[keyof User]
```

You can verify that `EventWatchParams` defined this way is equivalent to the union from before.

---

So, how does it work with this discriminated-union-of-rest-tuples version?  Well, with TypeScript 4.5 and below you will need to use `...args` and index into it with numeric indices.  It's a little ugly, but it is verified as type safe:

```
on(...args) {
  if (args[0] == 'ageChanged') {
    args[1](133) // okay
  }
}
```

The narrowing works; if `args[0]` is `ageChanged`, then `args[1]` is narrowed to `(e: number) => void`.

Once TypeScript 4.6 lands, you can improve this a little by destructuring `args` into your desired variable names and the [control flow analysis will still work](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6-rc/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions):

```
// TS4.6+
on(...args) {
  const [eventName, callback] = args;
  if (eventName == 'ageChanged') {
    callback(133) // okay
  }
}
```

This is about as good as you can get, though.  The ideal version where you write `on(eventName, callback)` instead of `on(...args)` is waiting on [microsoft/TypeScript#46680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46680) and it's not clear if that will be addressed anytime soon.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.1-rc#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJJAFwE8ZkBRANwmFIHURT4ALJAXjyJJIA8AaSQQAHqQYATKEgDWEcgHsAZkgCqUCGgB8ACgj1GAOXAQAXEgAGAElxCAvgGF2IYFghSrAGiTwQADYBAEYIcpYGlpraANpCALoAlNw6SLRKGFKJlumZANx8SA4FhIUUVBpaaNy8xPwqGGhQpKCQls2Y7iX8SAEgza0WSB0YXYUkIB6WwACuYMHa3fxKwJZ0DMysHEsORHt1ARCkSABWSuyrldo1BHUkDU0tZpYA5ABS58Av3uO9-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-lZar2fcjQRkMIxjAc-yDPhhFLHGMlzHJSwrB54FeUFLqEIcxxnBcD7VKuhSoQlQIfBcMZ-FFryguCiZ1lMSAJoUSLOY5rl+bULJsjMwAqNapCDawEABOQSAAO4YKQ7BKDMxzsKQpAwO5rJYHN7AzMEjnwEoYDMmAGDwFaUCqKQzIACqgQAymdGAwFdGBQFAMzQMyAAsABsP0ABwAAxIMoMwyRAnhkEoSAzFovzSl1PV1sAUhkOwDBIFI0PzcgUjQARMzwKNhGbsAaPIMA4jHAEozICmM3bUg11OF9jk-QA1L8B3AM066qeirGSWRPA9UsuYNghhYUkCollgyfUEjpRqmtC5psj2fYOoUjrBfsBUehc3p7uFSAVUG1VfM1DGVVGTWFCl7V1J1LloG5Fb8ES7I9TEgPC8WHiafLa6xq7UAxMa8QdqrXbq72-YIsOOslEAA)

Comment: This is a great answer. It is not easy to find reliable information about this problem. You really saved me from spending a lot of time researching. Thank you very much!